# How to match an RDD[ParentClass] with RDD[Subclass] in apache spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, subclass, rdd

I have to match an rdd with its types.

```
trait Fruit

case class Apple(price:Int) extends Fruit
case class Mango(price:Int) extends  Fruit
```

Now a dstream of type `DStream[Fruit]` is coming. It is either `Apple` or `Mango`.

How to perform operation based on the subclass? Something like the below (which doesn't work):

```
dStream.foreachRDD{rdd:RDD[Fruit] =>
     rdd match {
       case rdd: RDD[Apple] =>
         //do something

       case rdd: RDD[Mango] =>
         //do something

       case _ =>
         println(rdd.count() + "<<<< not matched anything")
     }
    }
```

Comment: How are you consuming data I mean what is source which sends data of type Apple or Mango ?

Comment: currently I am using the port (`nc -lk 12345`)

Comment: input is given as a json string and is parsed accordingly and i get the `dStream : DStream[Payload]`

Comment: Would a solution that pattern matches each row in each RDD work? I.e., for each rows that are Apple => do this, for each Mango row => do this, ignore and filter away other types.

Comment: `trait SentientBeing
trait Animal extends SentientBeing
case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal
case class Person(name: String, age: Int) extends SentientBeing

// later in the code ...
def printInfo(x: SentientBeing) = x match {
    case Person(name, age) => // handle the Person
    case Dog(name) => // handle the Dog
}` kind of should work...  is it not working? The simple way is @Shaido-ReinstateMonica suggested... you can filter the value of payload type and do processing based on filtered value

Comment: @potterpod: Did you manage to solve this problem? :)

Answer (score 2):

Since we have an `RDD[Fruit]`, any row can be either `Apple` or `Mango`. When using `foreachRDD`, each `RDD` will contain a mix of these (and possible other) types.

To differentiate between the different types, we can use [`collect[U](f: PartialFunction[T, U]): RDD[U]`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@collect[U](f:PartialFunction[T,U])(implicitevidence$29:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U]) (this is not to be confused with `collect(): Array[T]` that returns a list with the elements from the RDD). 
This function will return an RDD that contains all matching values by applying a function `f` (in this case, we can use a pattern match here).

Below follows a small illustrative example (adding `Orange` to the fruits as well).

Setup:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(1))
val inputData: Queue[RDD[Fruit]] = Queue()
val dStream: InputDStream[Fruit] = ssc.queueStream(inputData)

inputData += spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Apple(5), Apple(5), Mango(11)))
inputData += spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Mango(10), Orange(1), Orange(3)))
```

This creates a stream of `RDD[Fruit]` with two separate `RDD`s.

```
dStream.foreachRDD{rdd: RDD[Fruit] =>
  val mix = rdd.collect{
    case row: Apple => ("APPLE", row.price) // do any computation on apple rows
    case row: Mango => ("MANGO", row.price) // do any computation on mango rows
    //case _@row => do something with other rows (will be removed by default).
  }
  mix foreach println
}
```

In the above `collect`, we change each row slightly (removing the class) and then prints the resulting `RDD`. Result:

```
// First RDD
(MANGO,11)
(APPLE,5)
(APPLE,5)

// Second RDD
(MANGO,10)
```

As can be seen, the pattern match have kept and changed the rows containing `Apple` and `Mango` while removing all `Orange` classes.

---

**Separate RDDs**

If wanted, it is also possible to separate the two subclasses into their own `RDD`s as follows. Any computations can then be performed on these two `RDD`s.

```
val apple = rdd.collect{case row: Apple => row}
val mango = rdd.collect{case row: Mango => row}
```

---

**Complete example code**

```
trait Fruit
case class Apple(price:Int) extends Fruit
case class Mango(price:Int) extends  Fruit
case class Orange(price:Int) extends  Fruit

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(1))
    val inputData: Queue[RDD[Fruit]] = Queue()
    val inputStream: InputDStream[Fruit] = ssc.queueStream(inputData)

    inputData += spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Apple(5), Apple(5), Mango(11)))
    inputData += spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Mango(10), Orange(1), Orange(3)))

    inputStream.foreachRDD{rdd:RDD[Fruit] =>
      val mix = rdd.collect{
        case row: Apple => ("APPLE", row.price) // do any computation on apple rows
        case row: Mango => ("MANGO", row.price) // do any computation on mango rows
        //case _@row => do something with other rows (will be removed by default).
      }
      mix foreach println
    }

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Comment: @potterpod seems like this solved your probelm, if not please ask questions /respond.....  If you want to close the thread,  if you are okay please care to accept [the answer as owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/369717) and [vote-up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/369717)

Comment: Yes its helping, just one thing...on trying to get separate rdd's, Now I get  `RDD[DataFrame]` say for Apple, Now i want to write into a db. Now writing one after the other iterating in RDD[Dataframe] doesn't seems efficient. So is there a way to convert RDD[Dataframe] to Dataframe. Convert to a single dataframe and write it as a bulk into the db