# Why df write console format not showing anything?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a static dataframe, how to write it to the console instead of using `df.show()`

```
val sparkConfig = new SparkConf().setAppName("streaming-vertica").setMaster("local[2]")
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("local[2]").config(sparkConfig).getOrCreate()
val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext

val rows = sc.parallelize(Array(
  Row(1,"hello", true),
  Row(2,"goodbye", false)
))

val schema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("id",IntegerType, false),
  StructField("sings",StringType,true),
  StructField("still_here",BooleanType,true)
))

val df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rows, schema) 

df.write
  .format("console")
  .mode("append")
```

This is writing nothing into console:

```
 Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
20/04/27 00:30:59 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Process finished with exit code 0
```

On using save :

```
   df.write
      .format("console")
      .mode("append")
      .save()
```

It gives :

Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
20/04/27 00:45:01 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ConsoleSinkProvider does not allow create table as select.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:473)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
    at rep.StaticDFWrite$.main(StaticDFWrite.scala:35)
    at rep.StaticDFWrite.main(StaticDFWrite.scala)

Spark version = 2.2.1 
scala version = 2.11.12

Comment: you have to call an action, Spark is lazy and you did nothing but setting up the writer. The action would be `save`

Comment: Why is it giving an exception on using `save` @UninformedUser

Comment: Why are you saving to console? If you're only printing to console to debug, use `show()`

Comment: i have a situation in which it writes to a database, and there is something i need to check before verifying so I have brought down this piece of code as an example and see what happens in each line , that is the reason i am writing it to the console to make an exact replica and analyse the situation@DannyVarod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `save` on DataFrameWriter object.

without save method it will just create DataFrameWriter object & terminate your session.

Check below code, I have checked in spark-shell.

Please note this code is working on spark version 2.4.0 but not working on 2.2.0

console format will not work with write in spark 2.2.0 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20599

```
scala> df.write.format("console").mode("append")
res5: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter@148a3112

scala> df.write.format("console").mode("append").save()
+--------+---+
|    name|age|
+--------+---+
|srinivas| 20|
+--------+---+
```

Comment: It gives an exception on using save @Srinivas

Comment: why down vote.. you have call save() action on DataFrameWriter object

Comment: i dont know about downvote..
but i did the same thing in intellij and its giving an exception

Comment: which version of spark are you using ?

Comment: spark = 2.2.1 , scala = 2.11.12

Comment: are you using streaming libraries ?

Comment: yes `  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % spark2Version`

Comment: I have executed above code in spark 2.4.2 its working. its not working on 2.2.1

Comment: `  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % spark2Version` and `  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % spark2Version,
` and the verison is the one mentioned abov

Comment: yes. it will not supported this operation in spark 2.2.0

Comment: there was another situation could you please take a glimpse at it at the mean time :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61444973/how-to-match-an-rddparentclass-with-rddsubclass-in-apache-spark

Comment: I will accept it after confirming this is due to version

Comment: Check this - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20599 it is resolved in 2.3.0